# Accidentally deleted a folder from a NAS drive (My Book Live) – is there any way to recover this?

Tags: macos, data-recovery, nas

I accidentally deleted a folder from a NAS drive (My Book Live). Is there any way to recover it?

This is on a Mac. I know this may be a stretch, but I'm just hoping to find a solution.

Comment: That's what backups are for.

Comment: So the NAS was mounted on your Mac? Then the file never was on your Mac? Does the NAS have any sort of network recycle bin enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe My Book Lives use the Ext4 file system. The Ext file systems aren't very friendly for recovering deleted files, but there is an [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) software that you can try. Access the drive directly from a linux machine, and use that software, and it will use the file system's journal to allow for recovering some deleted files (as long as they haven't been overwritten in the empty space). You'll have to cross your fingers that the journal still has a record of it.

Beyond that, you'd have to do file recovery using file recovery software tools that can identify file types you need in raw data. This won't be as clean of a solution and you could lose filenames and metadata. Or you can send it in to a data recovery company - most will evaluate and give a no-obligation cost for free if recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

You could open it and put the hard drive('s) into your computer and use some sort of undelete application. More about this [here](http://www.diskinternals.com/nas-recovery/).

Comment: Depends on the filesystem used... If it's some special filesystem you might have trouble finding recovery software which'll read it.